# Can we display Cell values on heatmap in Spotfire?

Tags: heatmap, spotfire

Is it possible to display the cell values in the Heatmap without having to hover over the map?
If possible, could someone guide on how to achieve the same.

Comment: Not in a heat map but you can creat a cross table and apply a coloring scheme which achieves a similar result

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation and the alternate option

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set it by changing the hierarchy in the properties of the chart. Navigate to the Heatmap properties, and choose the "Hierarchy" from the navigation, and select the column for which the cell values needs to be displayed. Hope this helps.